# Spring webflow validator with no error message

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have spring webflow applicaiton, which has a contact info page and while submitting the form, it goes to spring validator.

And executing validations, if any wrong data then we adding a error message to validationcontext. Using ${errorMessags} we list the error messages.

But I have a scenario where I need to show a warning message to user in middle of page.
Either through spring validation or spring flowscope variable in Spring Validator

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that on validator?  Do you want to show that warning in next view?

I guess you could set message in  or in  to flashScope variable and show it on next page.